# node-inspector --webhost is not local! its a web app

Tags: node.js, node-inspector

if I enter

```
node --debug /home/engine/public_html/myapp.js
```

then in another putty tab

```
node-inspector --webhost http://website.com
```

I still get it telling me to open the browser and look locally...

```
Node Inspector v0.7.0-2
info  - socket.io started
Visit http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858 to start debugging.
```

Where as my site is online not local. When I do go to this address that inspector is telling me chrome says

```
This webpage is not available
```

I have opened ports 5858 and 8080 I can't see how this is suppose to work.

Comment: i'm not trying to access local host remotely. you have the wrong idea, in fact you have it totally backwards! I have a website (online not local), inspector keeps telling me to look locally!

Comment: I put it in my question that **the ports are open**! (?????at leastthe only i think it makes sense.?????) Are you dizzy bruv?

Answer (score 0):

Even i get the localhost url when I try to debug my remote site using node-inspector.

Try visiting the url *http://website.com/debug?port=port_number* after you start the inspector and app.

Here are the steps:

1. Start the Node Inspector server
   *$ node-inspector --web-port=5050*
2. Enable debug mode in your Node process
   *$ node --debug=5050 app.js*
3. Load the debugger UI
   *Open http://website.com/debug?port=5050 in the Chrome browser.*